# Get Twitter followers count from profile into a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets

In each Twitter profile page, there's information in the page code in JSON format that gives the number of followers. How can I grab the value of that and put it into a cell in a Google Sheet?

This information is the `<head>`, using NBC as an example here:

```
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "ProfilePage",
  "dateCreated": "2009-03-25T20:37:48.000Z",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "additionalName": "nbc",
    "description": "new shows coming this fall on NBC and streaming on @peacock. Need help? Tweet @nbcsupport.",
    "givenName": "NBC Entertainment",
    "homeLocation": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "name": "Across the globe"
    },
    "identifier": "26585095",
    "image": {
      "@type": "ImageObject",
      "contentUrl": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1613660668321988611/PMpussQQ_400x400.jpg",
      "thumbnailUrl": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1613660668321988611/PMpussQQ_normal.jpg"
    },
    "interactionStatistic": [
      {
        "@type": "InteractionCounter",
        "interactionType": "https://schema.org/FollowAction",
        "name": "Follows",
        "userInteractionCount": 2076530
      },
      {
        "@type": "InteractionCounter",
        "interactionType": "https://schema.org/SubscribeAction",
        "name": "Friends",
        "userInteractionCount": 703
      },
      {
        "@type": "InteractionCounter",
        "interactionType": "https://schema.org/WriteAction",
        "name": "Tweets",
        "userInteractionCount": 47059
      }
    ],
    "url": "https://twitter.com/nbc"
  },
  "contentRating": "",
  "relatedLink": [
    "https://example.com/KCPSTd1fbm",
    "https://youtube.com/NBC"
  ]
}</script>
```

I was trying to use the IMPORTXML function, but the XPATH that I was using wasn't working.

Is there a way to specifically target that value of userInteractionCount where name is Follows, so that I could pull the value of 2076530 into a cell in a Google Sheet?

Comment: Twitter doesn't render profile pages unless you're logged in. Google Sheets is probably only seeing the "Sign in to Twitter" page.

Comment: It may exist on the webpage when you view it in the browser, but you won't be able to get it with formulas or web scraping without using the Twitter API explicitly.